# Trigger all callback pattern matching in dash simultaneously

Tags: python, plotly-dash

My Dash app generates some content slowly.
However, I wanted the user to have some "quick content" without having to wait.
I found a solution to this by inserting empty containers, which trigger a callback to fill the contents.

For example:

```py
def make_layout(list_of_data_items):
    return [
        html.Div([
            html.Label(d),
            html.Span([], id=dict(type="more-data-from-source-A", index=d)),
            html.Span([], id=dict(type="more-data-from-source-B", index=d)),
        ])
        for d in list_of_data_items
    ]

@callback(
    Output(dict(type="more-data-from-source-A", index=MATCH), "children"),
    Input(dict(type="more-data-from-source-A", index=MATCH), "id"),
)
def add_data_from_source_A(data):
    # long execution
    return generate_more_data_for_item_for_source_A(data["index"])

@callback(
    Output(dict(type="more-data-from-source-B", index=MATCH), "children"),
    Input(dict(type="more-data-from-source-B", index=MATCH), "id"),
)
def add_data_from_source_B(data):
    # long execution
    return generate_more_data_for_item_for_source_B(data["index"])
```

Rather than firing the callback simultaneously for all matching items, it is triggered one-by-one.
Separate callbacks - e.g., `add_data_from_source_A` and `add_data_from_source_B` - may run simultaneously.
However, Dash only calls `add_data_from_source_A` one-at-a-time.

Is there a solution in which all the matched indexes are called simultaneously?